# Phase response for negative frequencies in a BodePlot

Tags: functions, bugs

As shown in the plot below, the phase response returned by the `BodePlot` function for negative frequencies is equal to zero. Is this correct? for me, the phase is an odd function (e.g. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40751/is-the-phase-of-a-digital-filter-always-an-odd-function-from-pi-pi).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] (*clear all symbols*)
p[s_] := 0.3576 - 0.1394*s^2 + 0.1721*s^4 - 0.1404*s^6
e[s_] := 0.3620 + 1.6452*s + 3.7021*s^2 + 4.9510*s^3 + 4.5715*s^4 + 2.5235*s^5 + s^6
s21[s_] := p[s]/e[s] (*transfer function*)
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[s21[s], s]
BodePlot[tfm, {-1.5, 1.5}, PlotLayout -> "Phase", ImageSize -> Large, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Radian"}] (*phase plot of the transfer function*)
```

[image]

### Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, the magnitude response given by the `BodePlot` function is symmetric around the $ \omega = 0 $ axis as expected (the magnitude response is an even function).

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of "negative" frequencies in your problem?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Trying to put in a simple way, when you design an electronic filter, you start with a low pass prototype (a filter whose pass band is normalized between $0 \leq \omega \leq 1$). If you mirror this prototype considering the $ \omega = 0 $ axis as the reference, you have a highpass prototype (in the negative frequencies). If you consider both (lowpass and highpass) prototypes, you have a bandpass prototype. From these prototypes, the desired filter type can be scaled to the proper frequency range.

Comment: If you plot the magnitude response, that is a even function, you can see the symmetry around the $\omega = 0$ axis. But the phase response does not keep this symmetry, indicating that the scaled filter response will not be correct.

Comment: I think this is a bug in `BodePlot` and `NicholsPlot`.

Comment: I agree with you @SubaThomas. Should I edit the question to add the "bug" tag?

Comment: Yes, you may add the bug tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the next release

```
BodePlot[tfm, {-1.5, 1.5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{"Linear", "dB"}, {"Linear", "Radian"}}]
```

[image]